# How do I tackle a proof of bounded sets

Tags: real-analysis

So we have this exercise (not homework, mind you), and I'm kind of clueless how to do it, as I'm not really good with mathematical proofs.

Anyway, the given task is this: Given nonempty and bounded sets A, B $\subseteq$ $\Bbb R$, prove that A $\cup$ B is bounded.

So there are (at least) two ways to do this, I think:
1) A is bounded and B is bounded $\Rightarrow$ A $\cup$ B is bounded
2) A $\cup$ B is not bounded $\Rightarrow$ **neither** A **nor** B is bounded (?)

I started by asking myself the question what it means that A and B are bounded. So, if A is bounded that means that:
- A has upper bounds. Let x $\in$ $\Bbb R$ be such an upper bound, that means that $\forall$a$\in$A: a $\le$ x
- A has lower bounds. Let y $\in$ $\Bbb R$ be such a lower bound, that means that $\forall$a$\in$A: y $\le$ a

Similarly for B, though the bounds for B may be different from those of A.

This is how far I have gotten, and now I'm stuck. Is what I've said so far correct? If it is, can you give me any hints on how to proceed from here on out?

Comment: Takes the max of the two upper bounds, and this is the upper bound for $A \cup B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are both bounded, then there exist $M_A,M_B\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a\le M_A$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\le M_B$ for all $b\in B$. Any element in $A\cup B$ is an element of $A$ or an element of $B$, or of both if they have non-empty intersection. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Given this and what Mauro said, I'd basically say this:

[...] Then M = max($M_A$, $M_B$) is an upper bound for A $\cup$ B, so that for every element c $\in$ A $\cup$ B it is c $\le$ M.  
Similarly for the lower bounds. But it feels as if though something is missing.

Comment: I don't think anything is missing. For any $c$ in the union you have $c\le M$, and for any $c$ in the union you have $m\le c$ (where $m$ is the minimum of the two lower bounds), and thus you have proved that $A\cup B$ is bounded.